# SERIAL увеличивает ID, даже если срабатывает CONSTRAINT

Tags: python, postgresql

Есть **ID** с типом **SERIAL**, то есть он автоинкрементирует число, после внесения данных.
Также есть второй столбец, условимся **Name** (varchar).

У *Name* есть ограничение на уникальность данных.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

Допустим в таблице было:

```
| ID | Name |
| 1  | Pavel|
```

Затем я пытаюсь внести данные, которые заведомо не подойдут по ограничению.

```
INSERT INTO users (Name) VALUES ('Pavel');
```

Сработает ошибка уникальности и данные не внесутся.

Далее я вношу новые, но уже подходящие данные.

```
INSERT INTO users (Name) VALUES ('Kristina');
```

Таблица принимает такой вид:

```
| ID |   Name   |
-----------------
| 1  | Pavel    |
| 3  | Kristina |
```

**Суть проблемы:** После неудачной попытки внести данные, автоинкремент увеличил значение ID и, при внесении новых данных, ID будет перескакивать порядок (пропущен ID со значением 2).

Конечно, это только эстетическая проблема по большей части, но мне хотелось бы знать, есть ли адекватный способ исправить это стандартным или не очень sql способом.

Так, как я использую в проекте python, то получилось "костыльно" решить задачу, но меня это не устравивает.

```py
def setval():
    cur.execute("SELECT ID, Name FROM users ORDER BY id;")
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM users;")
    for index, row in enumerate(data):
        cur.execute("""
            INSERT INTO users (ID, Name)
            VALUES (%s, %s)
        """, (index + 1, row[1]))
    cur.execute("""SELECT setval('users_ID_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users));""")
    adb.commit()
```

Comment: Насколько я понял и мне подсказал товарищ, потенциально можно использовать триггеры для обработки удачных и неудачных операций с логикой внесения ID.
Увы, с триггерами я ещё не работал, так что не могу точно сказать, стоит ли к такому подходу идти или нет.

Comment: Айдишники предназначены для машины. Пользователь вообще не должен знать об их существовании.

Comment: В моём проекте тегируются арты и М:М связь (таблицы: с артами, с тегами, связь к каждому арту множество тегов). 
Обращаться для тегирования к арту по его ID, которые последовательны в таблице, мне очень удобно и понятно. Я всё это визуализирую через таблицы в tkinter и все запросы происходят через поля ввода и кнопки. 
Я ознакомлен с нормами для бд, принятыми методиками и т д, но в этом конкретном случае, мне интересно было решить такую задачу и сделать архитектуру проекта именно таким образом. Но как будет лучше и, если можно так сказать, элегантнее, я не уверен.

Comment: Вообще этот вопрос много раз тут обсуждался. Зачем нужна эта эстетика - не очень понятно. Для отображения в `UI` вы можете сами пронумеровать записи как вам угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типы smallserial, serial и bigserial используют sequences и это нормально, что они оставляют пропуски в последовательности. В [документации об этом сказано](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

Так же там сказано, что это сделано не просто так и имеют под собой [обоснование, выделенное как "осторожно"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html). В частности для работы многопоточной обработки и избегания блокировок при вставке данных. Так же дополнительные сведения [приведены в FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_there_gaps_in_the_numbering_of_my_sequence.2FSERIAL_column.3F_Why_aren.27t_my_sequence_numbers_reused_on_transaction_abort.3F).

Поэтому если проблема только эстетическая, то лучше оставить реализацию как есть, чтобы не наплодить проблем в производительности и эксплуатации базы данных.

В остальном если необходимо, можно конечно использовать триггеры, вычисляемые значения, таблицу генерирующую идентификаторы, функции. И заодно самостоятельно пытаться решать проблемы, к которым это приведет.

---

***UPD***

К примеру, решение из того же FAQ с таблицей последовательности, которое ведет [на вопрос stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984196/postgresql-gapless-sequences/9985219#9985219).

Создаем функцию, которая будет вытаскивать ID из таблицы и обновлять их.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_next_id(countertable regclass, countercolumn text) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    next_value integer;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE %s SET %I = %I + 1 RETURNING %I', countertable, countercolumn, countercolumn, countercolumn) INTO next_value;
    RETURN next_value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Создаем таблицу и используем функцию.

```
CREATE TABLE example_seq ( last_id integer not null );
INSERT INTO example_seq VALUES (0);
```

```
create table example(
    id integer primary key not null default get_next_id('example_seq', 'last_id'),
    name text unique
);
```

Или можно найти другие решения по gapless sequences, к примеру:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/44E376F6.7010802@seaworthysys.com

Или попробовать max(id) + 1

Comment: Да, с пояснением в документации ознакомлен, знаю зачем так сделано. В конкретно моём случае это проблем никаких не создаст, а вот эстетически очень бы хотелось исправить, если не придётся полкода перелопатить.

Задал вопрос с целью найти более элегантное решение задачи, которое сам не смог исполнить.

Comment: @mrBars1k, обновил ответ.